# Update nodes detail in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, updatexml

I want to update some nodes in XML using XSLT. Like contact detail and Email.
Currently I am using  command like:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()*">  
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Metadata/contact/node/Email">    

      <xsl:variable name="OName" select="/Metadata/contact/organisationName/CharacterString"/>
      <xsl:variable name="Email" select="/Metadata/contact/node/Email/CharacterString"/>

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($OName,'TestOrg')">
              <CharacterString>
                <xsl:value-of select="'test@Test.com'"/>
              </CharacterString>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <CharacterString>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Email"/>
              </CharacterString>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
```

As Contact nodes are multiple and in each Contact node there are one organizaion name and email id. For ex of contact nodes are 3 and currently it fetch 3 values in $OName variable and $Email variable so nodes are not match. So how can I update only some nodes in xml using XSLT?

Comment: Please provide a source XML document and the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first template you have is a so called "[Identity template](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity#s1.)" and will loop through your complete source XML:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The second template you have will match on every `/Metadata/contact/node/Email`. I would write this template a little bit different. Instead of matching the absolute path, I think it is best to match the `Email/CharacterString` node and then perform your actions.

I would use a template like:

```
<xsl:template match="Email/CharacterString">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(ancestor::contact/organisationName/CharacterString,'TestOrg')">
                <xsl:value-of select="'test@Test.com'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Above template only matches the node you want to change (being `Email/CharacterString`). Once matches the `xsl:copy` copies the current selected node (`CharacterString`). The value will be filled depending on the value of `ancestor::contact/organisationName/CharacterString`. I am using the [XPath Axe](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) `ancestor` overhere. Which will be handy when changing the template.

If I would now change the template, for example only select the contact nodes that I would like to change, the second template can be written as:

```
<xsl:template match="contact[organisationRole/CharacterString = '1']/node/Email/CharacterString">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(ancestor::contact/organisationName/CharacterString,'TestOrg')">
                <xsl:value-of select="'test@Test.com'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I only apply the template to `contact` nodes where (`[]`) the `organisationRole/CharacterString` equals the value 1. Note that the body of the template did not change. Therefore you can see why the use of the [XPath Axe](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) is usefull.

**Complete XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contact[organisationRole/CharacterString = '1']/node/Email/CharacterString">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(ancestor::contact/organisationName/CharacterString,'TestOrg')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'test@Test.com'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metadata>
    <contact>
        <organisationRole>
            <CharacterString>1</CharacterString>
        </organisationRole>
        <organisationName>
            <CharacterString>TestOrg</CharacterString>
        </organisationName>
        <postalCode>
            <CharacterString>2020</CharacterString>
        </postalCode>
        <node>
            <Email>
                <CharacterString>some@user.com</CharacterString>
            </Email>
        </node>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <organisationRole>
            <CharacterString>2</CharacterString>
        </organisationRole>
        <organisationName>
            <CharacterString>Example Org</CharacterString>
        </organisationName>
        <postalCode>
            <CharacterString>8080</CharacterString>
        </postalCode>
        <node>
            <Email>
                <CharacterString>somebody@else.com</CharacterString>
            </Email>
        </node>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <organisationRole>
            <CharacterString>1</CharacterString>
        </organisationRole>
        <organisationName>
            <CharacterString>Real Org</CharacterString>
        </organisationName>
        <postalCode>
            <CharacterString>9050</CharacterString>
        </postalCode>
        <node>
            <Email>
                <CharacterString>user@example.com</CharacterString>
            </Email>
        </node>
    </contact>
</Metadata>
```

**Produced output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metadata>
    <contact>
        <organisationRole>
            <CharacterString>1</CharacterString>
        </organisationRole>
        <organisationName>
            <CharacterString>TestOrg</CharacterString>
        </organisationName>
        <postalCode>
            <CharacterString>2020</CharacterString>
        </postalCode>
        <node>
            <Email>
                <CharacterString>test@Test.com</CharacterString>
            </Email>
        </node>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <organisationRole>
            <CharacterString>2</CharacterString>
        </organisationRole>
        <organisationName>
            <CharacterString>Example Org</CharacterString>
        </organisationName>
        <postalCode>
            <CharacterString>8080</CharacterString>
        </postalCode>
        <node>
            <Email>
                <CharacterString>somebody@else.com</CharacterString>
            </Email>
        </node>
    </contact>
    <contact>
        <organisationRole>
            <CharacterString>1</CharacterString>
        </organisationRole>
        <organisationName>
            <CharacterString>Real Org</CharacterString>
        </organisationName>
        <postalCode>
            <CharacterString>9050</CharacterString>
        </postalCode>
        <node>
            <Email>
                <CharacterString>user@example.com</CharacterString>
            </Email>
        </node>
    </contact>
</Metadata>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you only want to change the `Email/CharacterString` from the contacts where the `organisationName/CharacterString` contains the text `TestOrg` the XSLT would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contact[contains(organisationName/CharacterString,'TestOrg')]/node/Email/CharacterString">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="'test@Test.com'"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems your variables selects need to be relative to the context node of your template:

```
<xsl:template match="/Metadata/contact/node/Email">    

  <xsl:variable name="OName" select="../../organisationName/CharacterString"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Email" select="CharacterString"/>
```

otherwise you will always start selecting from the root node for each match of the template and you will select all existing contact nodes every time.